# javascript check function for a html form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm having a problem with a HTML form (name, e-mail, subject, message), I can't validate the form if it was completed correct or not. I want to call a javascript function when the form is submitted and alert if a field wasn't completed correct.

My problem is with the submit button, because my boss said that I must use he's own php function to insert a submit button. The php function looke like:

```
function normal_button($text, $width, $param = '', $class = 'button-blue')
{
    $content = '<div class="'.$class.'" style="width:'.$width.'px;" '.$param.'>'.$text.'</div>';

    return $content;
}
```

and how I call the function:

```
echo normal_button('Send it', '100', 'onclick="document.getElementById(\'emailForm\').submit();" ');
```

I tried to call the js function declaring the `onSubmit="return checkForm(this)"` in the `<form action='email.php' method='post'>` HTML form, but I can't "catch" the submit. Also I tried to catch it with jquery, `$(document).ready(function() { $('.normal_button').click(function() { }); );` but I can't return false if a field wasn't completed correct.

I must use he's PHP function to insert the submit button, but how can I "catch" the fields, how can I validate them? Any suggestions? Thank you !

Comment: you are not inserting a submit button, you`re inserting a <div>

Comment: and show the whole form and the checkForm(this) function

Answer (score 1):

First of all, set ID for that form and for sbmit DIV button.

```
<form action='email.php' method='post' id='mailForm'>
```

and

```
echo normal_button('Send it', '100', 'id="mailFormSubmit"');
```

then do check with jQuery:

```
$('#mailFormSubmit').click(function(){
    // fields check code goes here

....

    // if all fields are OK, then submit form
    $('#mailForm').submit();
});
```